# Is there a way of finding if a subquery returns exactly one row? sql

Tags: sql

I have these two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    id_p number(3),
    name varchar2(35),
    email varchar2(35),
    adress varchar2(35)
);

CREATE TABLE Contract_j
(
    id_cj number(3),
    data date,
    object varchar2(30),
    onorary number(6),
    nr_pages number(4),
    id_client number(3),
    id_lawyer number(3)
);
```

id_p is the id of the person, and if that person is a client, id_p mathces with id_client

I have to find the name of the clients that have EXACTLY one legal assistance contract(Contract_j). How do I do that without using COUNT? I have to use at least one subquery and keywords suchs as ANY, ALL, IN, EXIST.

Comment: This sounds like homework. Stack Overflow is not a homework delivery service, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Alexia, the below query will give you the name of the clients that have EXACTLY one legal assistance contract. It uses a subquery and IN clause as per your constraints.

```
select name  
from 
Person 
where id_p in (
    select id_client
    from Contract_j 
    group by id_client
    having count(*)=1
)
```